# setLastModified on jsp UploadFile

Tags: java, jsp, last-modified, file-upload

I need help how to set the last modified time on a file uploaded (on jsp).
I need to know the time when the file uploaded. This is my code but eclipse says "The method setLastModified(Date) is undefined for the type UploadFile".

Code:

```
 UploadFile file = (UploadFile) files.get("uploadfile");

 fName =file.getFileName();

 file.setLastModified(getthetime()); 

 upBean.store(mrequest, "uploadfile");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the method you are trying to use is a method in the `java.io.File` API.  Change

```
file.setLastModified(getthetime());
```

to

```
new File(fName).setLastModified(getthetime());
```

---

For what it is worth, I'm surprised that this would be necessary.  I'd have thought that a file uploader would automatically set the modified time to the current time.  (Or more accurately, that it would do nothing ... and let the OS set it by default.)

What `FileUpload` class are you using?

Comment: im using javazoom.upload the time dont change i index the file and the time dont change that's why i have to setLastModified , and when i try the new File(fName).setLastModified(getthetime()); its work thaaaaank youuu ,sir you are good

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the message by Eclipse is self-explanatory. In the class UploadFile, there is no method called 'setLastModified'. Therefore, the compilation fails.

What is the fully-qualified classname of UploadFile class? Is it something that you wrote or is it from a third-party library?

Once you get a reference to the java.io.File object, use the setLastModified method in that class to set the time.

You might find it interesting to take a look at  Apache Commons File Upload library. It is a well known third-party library that is used to handle file upload operations in Java (see http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

This link http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html is an example of using Commons File Upload.